# Returning a partial view with Ajax, MVC 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

First let me say I think this site is a Godsend, and I am extremely grateful for all I've learned. I have an MVC3 component I'm working with. I want to populate a selectlist and when the user selects one of the options, I want a to load a partial view with the data displayed. Everything works so far except I'm missing the piece that refreshes the partial view. When the page originally loads, I see the empty  container in the code. I get no JS errors and Firebug shows the properly formatted HTML returned. So what part of the operation am I missing to refresh the partial view on the page? Please advise and thanx in advance.

The View:

```
    <tr>
  <th>Select a User to view their Roles:</th>
  <td><%=  Html.DropDownList("UserListForRoleView", list, "Please choose a User")%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
      <% Html.RenderPartial("ViewUsersInRole");%>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#UserListForRoleView').change(function () {
     var selectedID = $(this).val();
     $.get('/UserAdminRepository/ViewUsersInRole/?user=' + selectedID)
    });
 });
```

THe Controller:

```
   public ActionResult ViewUsersInRole()
    {
        string user = Request["user"];
        string[] selectedRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(user);
        List<string> data = new List<string>(); 
        if (selectedRoles.Length > 0)
        {
            data = selectedRoles.ToList<string>();
        }
        else
        {
            data.Add("No data found");
        }

        ViewData["UsersinRole"] = data;

        return PartialView("ViewUsersInRole");
    }
```

The PartialView (in it's entirety):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>
  <ul>
<%    
   List<string> list = ViewData["UsersinRole"] as List<string>;
   if (list != null && list.Count > 0)
   {
        foreach (string item in list)
      { %>
        <li><%: item %></li>
     <% }
   }
%>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: `$.get` takes a callback parameter that you're missing. You have to implement what happens when the response is received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

append html in the `td` like this:

```
<td id="partialcontainer">
  <% Html.RenderPartial("ViewUsersInRole");%>
</td>
```

and append html in it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#UserListForRoleView').change(function () {
       var selectedID = $(this).val(); 
    $.get('/UserAdminRepository/ViewUsersInRole/?user=' +  selectedID,function(response){

     $('#partialcontainer').html(response); 
          })
         });                            
       });
```

Little Improved code, always use `Url.Action` to generate url:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#UserListForRoleView').change(function () {

var selectedID = $(this).val();

var url = '@Url.Action("ViewUsersInRole","UserAdminRepository")';

url+"?user="+selectedID;

$.get(url,function(response){

$('#partialcontainer').html(response);

 });

 });

 });
```

I have modified a little your code to make it more clear and readable.

Comment: Thank! after a smidgeon of tinkering with the JS, this works wonders!

Comment: The edits you made cause a js error: "SyntaxError: missing } after function body"

Answer (score 0):

Try RenderAction

```
<% Html.RenderAction("ViewUsersInRole");%>
```